# Batch or Powershell Script to zip specific files

Tags: vba, powershell, batch-file, zip, 7zip

I have the following folder structure:

```
-Videos
  -1. Summer
    summer.mp4
    summer.srt
    summer2.zip
  -2. Winter
    winter.mkv
    winter.vtt
  - ..
```

How can I create a batch or powershell script that results in the following folder structure:

```
-Videos
  -1. Summer
    summer.mp4
    1. Summer.7z
  -2. Winter
    winter.mkv
    2. Winter.7z
  - ..
```

So basically iterate through all sub-folders, zip all the contents except video formats using 7zip and delete the original files that were zipped. I'm open to suggestions using VB!

Comment: Open any plain text editor, and type your code within it before saving it with a `ps1`/`.cmd` extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of research I managed to do it myself. Here's the answer for anyone with a similar situation:

```
@echo off
cls
set zip="C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
set loc=C:\User\Downloads\Videos\UnConverted

cd %loc%

for /d %%D in (%loc%\*) do (
    for /d %%I in ("%%D\*") do (
        cd %%I
        %zip% a -t7z -mx9 "%%~nxI.7z" *.txt *.html *.vtt *.srt *.zip *.jpeg *.png
        del /S *.txt *.html *.vtt *.srt *.zip *.jpeg *.png
    )
)

cd %loc%
echo ----- Compression Complete! -----
pause
```

The first for loop iterates through the every subfolder of the root folder while the second for loop iterates through each subfolder of the root folders subfolders. After that

```
cd %%I - To enter the sub-sub-folder
%zip% - To call the 7z cli
a - add files to archive
t7z - using the .7z extension
mx9 - with maximum compression
%%~nxI.7z - to store the files using the sub-sub-folders name
*.txt *.html *.vtt *.srt *.zip *.jpeg *.png - file extensions to archive
```

after that the del deletes the archived files.